# Are the expression for work: $W=0$ (for isochoric) and $W=p \Delta V$ (for isobaric) right also for irreversible processes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, pressure, work

I'm quite confused about isochoric and isobaric **irreversible** processes, and, in particular, the doubt is about **work W** in such processes.

If the processes is reversible (that is I can write $d W= p dV$) I have no problem in saying that

- In a isochoric process $W=0$, since $dV=0$.
- In a isobaric process $W=p(V_b-V_a)$ since $\int p dV=p \int dV$.

In other words, in both cases I can be sure that work is a state function (and, in particular, in isochoric is zero).

The problem is: I find in different textbooks that the previous expression for $W$ are used also in the cases of **irreversible** processes.

But in my view this is not correct because, to reach those conclusions about work it is fundamental to use $d W= p dV$, which holds true iff the process is  reversible.

So are the previous relations correctly or incorrectly used in the case of irreveresibility?

If so, can you suggest me any book/source that talks about canonical processes (isobaric, isochoric in particular) without saying that for **any** isochoric and isobaric process (irreversible or not) the previous ones are the expressions of work?

Comment: Work is not a state function.  For example, if I give you $(p, V, T)$ can you tell me the work?   Think about the distinction.   Keep in mind that work (and heat) are quantities of energy that enter or leave the system *during a process*.

Comment: I'm wondering why do you have problem when the process is irreversible. Is there any reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An isochoric process is by definition when $dV=0$ irrespective of being reversible or irreversible. Whether $\delta W = pdV$ depends on what you mean by $p$. If by $p$ you mean the *external* pressure then it is true irrespective of the nature of the process, and then you can say that $\delta W$ is the *external* work, that is the work done by external forces on the system that has suffered volume change $dV$. If by $p$ you mean the internal pressure, even if it is homogeneous across the system, then the equation holds when the process is reversible, and does not hold if it is irreversible.

Comment: Well said!!!!!!

Comment: @hyportnex But only if non-PV work is zero, right? Otherwise $\delta W = p_{ext}dV + \delta W_{nonPV} \ne p_{ext} dV$

Comment: @ManRow In general, let $p_0$ denote the externally imposed pressure and let $p$ be the internal system pressure. Then $dU=TdS-pdV=\delta q_0 - p_0 dV$, denoting the external work by $p_0dV$. When the process is irreversible then you have both $TdS- \delta q_0 = pdV -p_0dV > 0$, therefore, $p > p_0$ for $dV>0$ (an expansion work) and $p<p_0$ for $dV<0$ (a compression work). If $dV=0$ then all you have is $TdS>\delta q_0$. For some more details read this https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/801867/clausius-inequality-and-thermodynamic-potentials/801872#801872